# UWP Toast Message not apearing in Windows 11

Tags: uwp, toast, windows-11

UWP Toast notification is not displaying(appearing in front) in Windows 11 Beta

But same thing is working on Windows 10

Sample Code:

```
var toastNotifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();

ToastContent  content = new ToastContentBuilder()
                            .AddText(message)
                            .AddAppLogoOverride(new Uri(this.LogoUri))
                            .GetToastContent();

// Create the notification
ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(content.GetXml());
toast.ExpirationTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(this.ToastDisplayTime);
toastNotifier.Show(toast);
```

Is Toast Notification Mechanism updated in windows 11 ?

Comment: Currently Windows 11 is preview version, if you have any problem please feel free post it with windows feed back hub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems in latest windows 11 problem fixed

Answer (score 5):

I had this same problem.

It seems Windows 11 has Focus Assist enabled by default. To disable it or configure it, simply look for "Focus Assist" in Windows Settings.

Comment: Any workaround for this? I don't remember turning it on, is it on by default? is there anyway to throw an error/logit if notification are prevented?

Comment: @Axeltherabbit it is on by default. I don't think there is a way to "alert" your application when the notification does not show.

Comment: RIght, that's kinda annoying.